# Select Last Childs in a self-joined table in EF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, self-join

I have a table like this :

```
Id              int      Not Null  PK Unique
RequestNO       int      Not Null   
RefrenceId      int      Null                  //Self Join to Id
```

If I have these records in this table :

```
Id   RequestNO    RefrenceId      
1       H100         NULL
2       H101         NULL
3       H101          2
4       H101          3
5       H100          1
6       H105         NULL
```

Depend on these records I want to return a list where Id is in { 4 ,5 , 6 }.I want to select last childrens (If any parents have not childs, itself is a child). Is there any one to help me about this ?!!

I am using EF 4 (Database First) , and the table name is **Requests**

**UPDATE1** : I try this , but it failed.

```
var list = DataContext.Requests.GroupBy(rec => new { rec.ConfirmNo }).Select(rec => rec.FirstOrDefault());
```

If you need more details comment me.
Thanks 
Ali Foroughi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var list = DataContext.Requests.Where(op => !DataContext.Requests.Any(ip => ip.RefrenceId == ip.Id));
```

Comment: As I know there is nothing like Exists in EF4 . maybe i shoult to use Any . Am I right ?!

Comment: You helped me , Thank you dude

Comment: Ya..there is no extension method called `Exists` in EF4. I tried it with LINQ to Objects and pasted the code. I'm glad it helped you and thanks for the edit.